# A few questions regarding; openness of sets, pavings and Borel sets.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm looking at some problems for my measure theory class, and there are a few that I have trouble with, that I really hope you can help me out with.

The setup is as follows:

First we define the mapping $\omega: \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ as the angle between any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and the $x$-axis.

Second we define the sets:

$H(r,R)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\|_2 \in (r,R)\}$

$K(\theta,\nu\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \omega(x) \in (\theta,\nu)\}$

$B(\theta,\nu,r,R)=H(r,R) \cap K(\theta,\nu)$

Finally we define the paving, $\mathbb{D}$, as the set of all $B(\theta,\nu,r,R)$ and $H(r,R)$ with $0\leq \theta \leq \nu \leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq r \leq R$

Now, the problems that are giving me a hard time, are the following:

1. Show that the sets $B(\theta,\nu,r,R)$ and $H(r,R)$ are open, and that $\mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{B_2}$ (where $\mathbb{B_2}$ is the Borel set on $\mathbb{R}^2$)
2. Show that $\sigma(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{B_2}$
3. Show that $\sigma(\mathbb{D}) \supset \mathbb{B_2}$

For the first one, I can see that these sets are open, but I am just so bad at showing it - but once it's shown, the fact that $\mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{B_2}$ is trivial, since $\mathbb{B_2}$ is generated by all the open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I think, at least.

The second and third one I'm pretty lost on.

I really hope someone can give me a few good hints to get me started with this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For the first one, would openness of both $H(r,R)$ and $K(\theta,\nu)$ imply openness of $B(\theta,\nu,r,R)$?

Comment: The claim in your edit is true, since a finite intersection of open sets remains open.  Hint for (2) and (3): note that if $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $A \subset B$, then $\sigma(A) \subset B$.

Comment: Okay, I think I've solved (1) and (2) correctly now using that, thanks!
I'm still not sure about (3), though. $\mathbb{B}_2$ is, of course, a sigma algebra, but what's the argument, that $\mathbb{B}_2 \subset \sigma(\mathbb{D})$? Using the hint you've given above, I'd still have to somehow argue that $\mathbb{B}_2 \subset \sigma(\mathbb{D})$, which I'm unsure how to do.

Comment: My hint still works for (3) when you note that $\mathbb{B}_2$ is (as you observed) the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets.  Or equivalently $\mathbb{B}_2 = \sigma(B)$ where $B$ is the collection of open balls.  So, by the hint, it suffices to show that $B \subset \sigma(\mathbb{D})$, since this implies $\mathbb{B}_2 = \sigma(B) \subset \sigma(\mathbb{D})$.

In other words, you just need to take an arbitrary open ball and show that it lives in $\sigma(\mathbb{D})$.

Comment: Ahh, that's genius! Thank you so much, you've been extremely helpful! :-)